# Is there a generic Hudson reporter?

Tags: hudson

Our build has a variety of generated HTML reports.  I would like to have those reported and accessible on the build page, like JavaDoc entries.  Is there a generic way to expose these reports without writing a custom plug ins ?

If that isn't available, is there a way to post an HTTP link on the page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose "archive the artifacts" and archive for example "reports/*.html"

These will appear under the project page under the heading "Last successful artifacts".

Even if you clear your workspace before each build, these artifacts are moved to a separate directory.

You could also add a build script which will modify or update a file in your userContent directory (since Hudson 1.299), and link to these build artifacts in yet another location.

Comment: Note that if you have artifacts from previous reports hanging around in your workspace directory, and they match the artifacts filter, they will get copied again, because Hudson marks them as artifacts of the latest build. If you archive the fingerprints (MD5 sums) of the artifacts, it will be able to report in what other builds the same artifacts appeared in.